# What day and time does the guild rep cap reset?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

What day and time does the guild rep cap reset? I play on the US Wildhammer, a central time zone, realm. However, please answer this question so that it helps anyone from another realm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weekly cap resets along with Daily Quests, at 3 AM, server time, on Tuesday Morning for US servers, and at 3 AM server, Wednesday morning for EU servers.

Answer (score 2):

Resets when all your realm resets occur, this is not the same moment on all realms.

Answer (score 0):

It resets (for most characters) at the same time as the raid resets, etc, which tends to be 3 AM Tuesday morning for the U.S. or Tuesday night for Oceania.  However I've heard reports that it varies for some characters, and they may reset at 3 AM Monday mornings (U.S. time) or other times during the week.  However I haven't experienced that myself.

Comment: Actually, raids and other instances reset around Noon. It's just that realms are usually down between 3 and 12 on Tuesdays anyway, rendering the difference somewhat moot.

Answer (score 0):

I also play on Wildhammer and Guild Rep resets at 4Am realm time, and so will your daily quests. Hope to see you on sometime!